# div width 100% +10px: relative to parent?

Tags: html, css, menu, width, css-position

I have a ul/li menu with display:table/table-cell:auto layout, stretched to fill the container and distribute horizontal space between menu items. I have to align an additional UI element to the last menu item. I can achieve this by adding that element as a child of the last li element and making it 100% wide.

However, I need to position this UI element (language selector) partially outside of the main content, so I position this by a relative right:-10px. But the side effect is that the left edge of the selector moves to the right, compared to the menu element. Normally I'd increase the selector div's width by 10px, but since it's 100%, I can't do that. And the parent li's width is determined by its text content.

Is there a way to get this right using pure css? I can't add padding on the selector, because I need its child content to fill the whole div.

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">first</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">second</a>
            <div id="selector">
                <a href="#">EN</a>
                <a href="#">FR</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hJXng/13/

Comment: Is this what you're going for? I removed the -10px right rule, and added some left padding and a background color to match. http://jsfiddle.net/hJXng/16/

Comment: Thanks, nope, see: "I can't add padding on the selector, because I need its child content to fill the whole div" at the end. The padding won't change its color when hovering over the anchors. At least not with a pure css solution I'm aware of. (BTW, I had implemented a very similar solution with right padding and onmouseover bg-color change on the #selector before posting my question.)

Comment: A small comment: your use of `display:table`, `table-cell`, etc, makes it difficult to use most CSS tricks I tried (for example - absolute in relative, or negative margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where xpy's answers have gone, but his/her comments finally made my day. Had to add two wrapper divs, since a div with "display: table" didn't fill the padding in Chrome, while "display: block" did. So absolute positioning a 100% wide block div inside another padded div actually works.

```
#selector-full {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cPDd6/4/

Answer (score 11):

Depending on what browsers you want to support, a simple option is to use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc):

```
width: calc(100% + 10px);
```

See also: [Can I use `calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hJXng/19/

Comment: Thanks Kobi, nice. Though I have to support IE8, bummer.

Comment: I've been searching for somethign like this for a while now!! Thank you!